# Per-item converter instance in style of treeview item container

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have `ItemContainerStyle` set for `TreeView` and use `MultiBinding` with converter in it:

```
<TreeView>
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SelectedCategoryConverter}" Mode="TwoWay">
                            <Binding Path="."/>
                            <Binding Path="CurrentCategoryId" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />

            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

I need `SelectedCategoryConverter` to be created for every unique item in the tree view, so I declared it with `x:Shared="False"` in window resources:

```
<local:SelectedCategoryConverter x:Shared="false" x:Key="SelectedCategoryConverter"/>
```

but it doesn't help: only one instance of converter is created when 2 or more items passed to TreeView through ItemsSource. I tried to write converter as  `MarkupExtension`, but it didn't help too.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is only one way.

1. Move ItemContainerStyle to the resource and marked it as nonshared:

```
<Application.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" x:Shared="False">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{local:SelectedCategoryConverterCreator}" Mode="TwoWay">
                            <Binding Path="."/>
                            <Binding Path="CurrentCategoryId" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />    
            </Style>
        </Application.Resources>
<TreeView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}">
```

2. Create your own MarkupExtension which will create a new instance of SelectedCategoryConverter:

   public class SelectedCategoryConverterCreatorExtension : MarkupExtension
   {
       public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
       {
           return new SelectedCategoryConverter();
       } 
   }

It will create a new instance of SelectedCategoryConverter for each item. But remember that it is not very memory efficient.

Comment: Two instances of converter are created, but for unknown reason the only last of it used to convert value for both items(

Comment: @FLCL Did you checks hash code of SelectedCategoryConverter whether only the last created instance is really called?

Comment: I used debugger's object id